# How to eager load with Include() only if not null?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am trying to do:

```
var abc = Context.PersonSet.Include(p=>p.Child).ToList();
```

But not all Persons have a Child. So I get:

[image: Type Error]
I would like to get all Persons, and if the Child is not null, I want to Include it. It would be also ok to Include Child as null.

Comment: That code line as such should not cause an error I think. Are you sure the error is coming from that line? Are you doing anything special in the constructor of the Person class?

Answer (score 11):

I don't know why people keep upvoting the solutions like this:

```
Include(p => p.NavProp ?? new List<NavPropType>())
```

Because that won't work, that is invalid for `Include()`:

> InvalidOperationException:
>
> The Include property lambda expression `p => (p.NavProp ?? value(System.Collections.Generic.List'1[NavPropType]))` is invalid. The expression should represent a property access: `t => t.MyProperty`.
>
> To target navigations declared on derived types, specify an explicitly typed lambda parameter of the target type, E.g. `(Derived d) => d.MyProperty`. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

The solution: declare your property with a default value:

```
public class Foo
{
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; } = new List<Bar>();
}
```

This makes sure `Bars` won't be `null` when no related records are found.

Comment: Good answer, but i wonder what if i have a relationship created ?

Answer (score 6):

return empty child instead of null

```
 Context.PersonSet.Include(a => ((a.Child == null) ? new Collection<Child>() : a.Child));
```

Comment: I prefer this one over giving a property in the model a default empty collection because now you can still easily tell when you in fact have a DB NULL in the database.

Answer (score 3):

You can use GroupJoin to get all persons and load their children if they have any child:
(consider that in this approach you should have DbSet of Children in your context)

```
Context.PersonSet.GroupJoin(Context.Children, p => p.Id, c => c.PersonId, (p, c) =>
                 new { Person = p, Child = c }).ToList();
```

Comment: +1 since using GroupJoin (carefully!) also gives you more control over the SQL generated by EF. Just using Include() can lead to some very inefficient SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The exception shouldn't be coming from that line. `Include()` should be using a `LEFT JOIN` which does exactly what you're asking for: *"I would like to get all Persons, and if the Child is not null, I want to Include it"*. To confirm that, check the SQL that is generated from your LINQ.

To fix the issue, look at the code that is using the result of the query `abc` and see if it is processing the `Child` collection properly (i.e. checking if the collection is empty).

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following approach:

```
var abc = Context.PersonSet.Include(p=>p.Child).Where(p=>p.Child!=null).ToList();
```